# No package called rodbc

Tags: r, rodbc

I am using R Studio where I have installed RODBC successfully as it works fine when I run a .r script. However, when I use the very same code in an .Rmd file I get an error saying

> Error in library("rodbc") : there is no package called 'rodbc'
>   Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> library"

Comment: it's RODBC, uppercase

Comment: install.packages("RODBC")

Answer (score 2):

Please note that R is case sensitive. You have written in lowercase thats the reason you are getting error.

You can write like:

```
library("RODBC")
```

or

```
library(RODBC)
```